# How to make text field only accept decimal figures

Tags: java, netbeans, decimal, textfield

Basic enough problem I think. I want to make my text field only accept decimal(double) numbers. Here's the code I have at the moment, it only allows integers.

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {  

char c = evt.getKeyChar();

if((Character.isDigit(c)||c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE||c==KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL)) {

    evt.consume(); 

}
```

Comment: you want the user to only be able to type in numbers + point "." + the letter e + numbers for an exponent?    Or just numbers and the decimal sign?

Comment: Have you looked at any regular expression? You can check if the user is inserting a comma or a period after a number.

Comment: Just numbers and decimal sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with it:

```
try{
  Double.parseDouble(number);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
  // Not a double
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Text field has a `Document`, it should be a `PlainDocument`. Get the backing `PlainDocument` and inject in your own `DocumentFilter` into it. Your own filter should extend `DocumentFilter`, overridding [`insertString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html#insertString(javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet)) to only call `super.insertString` for valid characters (in your case digits).

`insertString`'s Javadocs:

> Invoked prior to insertion of text into the specified Document.
>   Subclasses that want to conditionally allow insertion should override
>   this and only call supers implementation as necessary, or call
>   directly into the FilterBypass.